# How do I convert the Google Maps mysql query to oracle, and is there a performance hit?

Tags: oracle, oracle10g, oracle11g

I am trying to find businesses within 25 miles of a point, and saw Google's "correct" MySQL query here (http://code.google.com/apis/maps/articles/phpsqlsearch.html#findnearsql) :

```
SELECT id, (3959 * acos(cos(radians(37)) * cos(radians(lat)) * 
cos(radians(lng) - radians(-122)) + sin(radians(37)) * sin(radians(lat)))) 
AS distance FROM markers HAVING distance < 25 ORDER BY distance LIMIT 0 , 20;
```

However, my database is in Oracle and I wanted to convert this query to oracle, so here is what I created, which seems to be working as well.

```
SELECT id, ( 3959 * acos( cos( degree2radian(41.912434) ) * cos( degree2radian( latitude ) ) * cos( degree2radian( longitude ) - degree2radian(-87.6357596) ) + sin( degree2radian(41.912434) ) * sin( degree2radian( latitude ) ) ) ) AS distance 
FROM markers 
GROUP BY id, latitude, longitude 
HAVING ( 3959 * acos( cos( degree2radian(41.912434) ) * cos( degree2radian( latitude ) ) * cos( degree2radian( longitude ) - degree2radian(-87.6357596) ) + sin( degree2radian(41.912434) ) * sin( degree2radian( latitude ) ) ) )  < 25 ;
```

where, I also defined a function:

```
create or replace
FUNCTION degree2radian(pin_Degree IN NUMBER)
    RETURN NUMBER DETERMINISTIC IS
BEGIN
    RETURN pin_Degree / 57.2957795; --1R = 180C
END degree2radian;
```

It seems like everything is working but I am not sure whether I converted the query correctly, and if so, is there any performance issues, or any ways I can clean this query up (ie. DRY principle etc.)???

Comment: This would be used on a 12K row database, and I actually need to return the 'id' as a column because I have to reference it on the front-end of my website.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oracle doesn't appear to have a native function for it, so I'd suspect you'd be fine doing it that way.

Cheap solution:  Violate normalization and the degrees value in a radians column using a trigger.

Expensive solution:  Buy Oracle Spatial, which can answer spatial questions of this nature faster due to the use of r-tree indexing.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know your table structure, but a group by clause with id in it looks strange. Is it actually doing anything? Or could you drop the group by and replace having with where.

In any case oracle will not be able to use an index on that query, which might or might not be a problem.

If it is I can see the following approaches:
- oracle has some special 'spatial' features, there might be something usefull in there for you
- you might add a where close, restricting the result using a simpler outer bound. The idea behind that is, that and index can be used on that constraint and only the smaller result need to get checked against the complex constraint